# Validate user input against the DB value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I am build my first .NET Core MVC application and using the Entity Framework. I have a edit page where users are allowed to enter the Quantity that they would like to order. The model classes are like below

```
public partial class Inventory
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int QuantityAvailable { get; set; }
        public string RoomNumber { get; set; }
        public int InventoryId { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int? QuantityReq { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class Item
{
    public int CustomId { get; set; }
    public Inventory Inventory { get; set; }
}
```

The `QuantityReq` doesnot exists in the DB so I added them as `NotMapped`. So I have a view name is `AddtoOrder` on the Item like

```
@model JAXSurplusMouseApp.Models.Item

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h4>Add to Order</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="AddtoOrder">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
           <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Inventory.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Inventory.Name" class="form-control" readonly />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Inventory.QuantityAvailable" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Inventory.QuantityAvailable" class="form-control" readonly />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Inventory.RoomNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Inventory.RoomNumber" class="form-control" readonly />
            </div>
        </form>
        <form method="post"
              asp-controller="Inventories"
              asp-action="OrderItem">
            <label class="control-label">Quantity Required</label>
            <input type="text" id="quantityReq" name="quantityReq" value=@Model.Inventory.QuantityReq />
            <input type="hidden" id="customerID" name="customerID" value="@Model.CustomId" />
            <input type="hidden" id="invetoryID" name="invetoryID" value="@Model.Inventory.InventoryId" />
            <button type="submit"><u>Order</u></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

The Controller action is like below, if the user entering the quantity is more than the Quantity that is available then the order is placed and it navigates back to the other page. But if users enter a number in the Quantity required that is more than the Quantity Available then I need to post a error message in the same page that they have entered invalid quantity

```
// Action to launch the AddtoOrder page 
public async Task<IActionResult> AddtoOrder(int? inventoryID, int? custID)
 {
    if (inventoryID == null || custID == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    Customer custData = await _context.Customers.FindAsync(custID);
    var inventories = await _context.Inventories.FindAsync(inventoryID);
    var model = new Item
    {
        CustomId = (int)custID,
        Inventory = inventories
    };
    return View(model);
}

//Action athat allows the users to submit the order
 public async Task<IActionResult> OrderItem(int? customerID, int? invetoryID, int quantityReq)
    {
        if (customerID == null || invetoryID == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        Customer custData = await _context.Customers.FindAsync(customerID);
        var intData = await _context.Inventories.FindAsync(invetoryID);

            if (quantityReq <= intData.QuantityAvailable && quantityReq > 0)
            {
                InventoryOrder io = new InventoryOrder();
                io.OrderQuantity = quantityReq;
                io.InventoryId = (int)invetoryID;
                _context.Add(io);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                intData.QuantityAvailable = intData.QuantityAvailable - quantityReq;
                _context.Update(intData);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();  
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Inventories", new { id = customerID });              
            }

            else if (quantityReq > intData.QuantityAvailable){
                 How to redirect to the same page back with the  validation error                 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you should add `@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "error" })` to your form. Also, I would recommend you use [HTML Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs#understanding-html-helpers).

This is simple example of form:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Age)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age)
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "error" })
    }
```

And then you can custom validate your model and send error to View:

```
// Validation logic
else if (quantityReq > intData.QuantityAvailable) 
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("QuantityReq", "QuantityReq more than QuantityAvailable");
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I am here using the EF Framework to get the data for the other fields only the `QuantityReq ` that is what I am marking as `NotMapped` so we can allow users enter it. How can I have the HTML helpers only for the `QuantityReq ` field

Comment: Try this `ModelState.AddModelError("", "QuantityReq more than QuantityAvailable");` It will show common error for entire form.

Comment: Also, you can change your HTML and add HTML helper only for this filed `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.QuantityReq)`. It will generate such HTML `<input class="form-control" id="QuantityReq" name="QuantityReq" type="text" value="" />`

Comment: I am running to an issue. When I tried to enter more quantity to test the Redirect is not working.  The  name of the action and the view name is different so the `return View();` returned error saying the view `OrderItem` doesnot exists. The view name `AddtoOrder` So I tried to navigate to the view by doing `return RedirectToAction("AddtoOrder", "Inventories", new { inventoryID = invetoryID, custID = customerID });` it returned back to the page but I dont see the error message

Comment: I updated my question. Actually the `AddtoOrder` view is launched from the previous page on click of the button which passes some parameters to populate the fields.. The validation is happens in a different action so how can I navigate back to the `AddtoOrder` page from the `OrderItem` action showing the validation error

Comment: `ModelState` save state only for the current model and current page. If you want go back and show error on previous page - I would recommend to create own mechanism to show some errors. For example create `List<string> Errors` - the list of errors for model. And send model this error on previous page - RedirectToAction with error list. On the view - check this list - `Errors.Any()` and show custom error message. It is simple solution for your situation